# Flex-Flash frontend for Wordpress

Tags: apache-flex, flash, wordpress

We all know what Wordpress can do with a little bit of css goodness. I was wondering whether the idea could be extended even further and make a completely separate Flash/Flex frontend for a website, that uses Wordpress in the back. That would certainly be possible. I was just wondering whether its practical. Any progress on the topic ?

Comment: It's possible but I do not know why one might want to do that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.arpitonline.com/blog/2007/03/24/wordpress-in-flexas3/

http://www.asual.com/blog/swfaddress/flex-on-wordpress.html

http://www.wonderhowto.com/how-to-convert-wordpress-adobe-flex-3-application-255415/

Answer (score 0):

very similar question asked on built4flash

http://built4flash.stackexchange.com/questions/178/any-blogging-software-written-in-flex

simply put, it'd have to completely wrap the wordpress, unless you use PHP connection into wordpress routines, but this would be an addon/extension style build and not an integration.

Answer (score 0):

http://flashcms.patrick-segarel.com

Wordpress, Zend Framework and AS3

Wordpress is used as a library item in order to access all the Wordpress functions within the ZF application, the retrieved data is sent to Flash via ZendAmf